# JavaFX: Динамический контент GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

1. Есть форма, в ней есть GridPane. В GridPane есть элементы, предположим Rectangle (квадраты), а форма может растягиваться вместе с GridPane
   Как сделать чтобы если форма стала шире (вместе с GridPane), элементы то что были ниже переместились в свободное место справа и наоборот, если форма стала уже, то элементы что не влезают справа, переместились вниз
2. Добавлять динамически при нажатии кнопки Rectangle не задавая ячейки (в свободное место ниже и выше сдвигая остальные элементы)

Comment: Для таких целей возможно подойдут VBox и HBox

Answer (score 3):

Ну касательно первого пункта вот вам развернуты пример кода с слушателем ответственным за подобные изменения:

```
public class ResizableGridPane extends Application {

    private static final Double rectaWidth = 100d, rectaHeigth = 50d;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(grid);

        grid.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());

        Rectangle a = new Rectangle(rectaWidth, rectaHeigth);
        a.setFill(Color.RED);
        Rectangle b = new Rectangle(rectaWidth, rectaHeigth);
        b.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        Rectangle c = new Rectangle(rectaWidth, rectaHeigth);
        c.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        Rectangle[] recta = { a, b, c };

        grid.prefWidthProperty().addListener((e) -> {
            int colums = (int) (((DoubleProperty) e).getValue() / rectaWidth);
            colums = colums < 1 ? 1 : colums > recta.length ? recta.length % colums : colums;
            for (int row = 0; row < Math.ceil(((double) recta.length / (double) colums)); row++) {
                for (int colum = 0; colum < colums; ++colum) {
                    if (((row * colums) + colum) < recta.length)
                        grid.setConstraints(recta[(row * colums) + colum], colum, row);
                }
            }
        });

        grid.getChildren().addAll(a, b, c);

        Scene s = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Слушатель динамически отслеживает ширину панели и соответсвенно подгоняет колличество столбцов перемещая каждый раз все прямоугольнии...Вполне верным будет решение с хранением теущих индексов положения обектов в сетке в неком классе моделе и использовать такое решение для динамичесого добавления обекта в сетку...Это уже ближе к 2ой части вопроса...

Answer (score 2):

Без написания своих велосипедов можно использовать [FlowPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html) или стороннее решение - [GridView](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html).

Comment: Ссылка на GridView вроде протухла, пусть будет [github](https://github.com/jinghai/controlsfx/blob/master/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.java)